# php change item array to row

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

For this:

```
$input = [
'class a' => [
    'A' => [
        'name' => 'Allen',
        'score' => 90   
    ],
    'B' => [
        'name' => 'Bill',
        'score' => 80
    ]
],
'class b' => [
    'A' => [
        'name' => 'Cate',
        'score' => 90   
    ],
    'B' => [
        'name' => 'Dave',
        'score' => 80
    ]
],
'class c' => [] 
    'A' => [
        'name' => 'Gill',
        'score' => 90   
    ],
    'B' => [
        'name' => 'Hill',
        'score' => 80
    ]
];
```

, the desired output is:

```
$output = [
'0' => [
    '0' => 'Allen',
    '1' => 90,
    '2' => 'Cate',
    '3' => 100
    '4' => 'Gill'
    '5' => 90
],
'1' => [
    '0' => 'Bill',
    '1' => 80,
    '2' => 'Dave',
    '3' => 70,
    '4' => 'Hill',
    '5' => 70
]
];
```

How can I do this? And when classes number isn't the same how to do it?

I tried `array_column` and `array_values` but I don't get the right output.

Comment: A loop could help.. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @SougataBose this is just a similiar situation to my real project,the real matter is much more complicat,I just ask here for a more effective way

Answer (score 0):

Make columns of your multidimensional array by key using `array_column()` and loop every array using `foreach` loop and assign name and score in a single array and insert both array into a new array;

```
$arr1 = array_column($input, 'A');
$arr2 = array_column($input, 'B');

foreach($arr1 as $arrn){
$arrnew1[]=$arrn['name'];
$arrnew1[]=$arrn['score'];
};

foreach($arr2 as $arrn){
$arrnew2[]=$arrn['name'];
$arrnew2[]=$arrn['score'];
};

$array = [$arrnew1, $arrnew2];

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
// Keys to extract
$keys = array('A', 'B');

$new = array();
// Loop through the keys
foreach($keys as $i => $key) {
   $temp = array();
   // Set the values from extracted array 
   array_map(function($v) use(&$temp ) {
       $temp[] = $v['name'];
       $temp[] = $v['score'];       
   }, array_column($input, $key));
   $new[$i] = $temp;
}
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Allen"
    [1]=>
    int(90)
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Cate"
    [3]=>
    int(90)
    [4]=>
    string(4) "Gill"
    [5]=>
    int(90)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Bill"
    [1]=>
    int(80)
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Dave"
    [3]=>
    int(80)
    [4]=>
    string(4) "Hill"
    [5]=>
    int(80)
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/635803)